# ffmpeg x264 encoding cpu usage

Tags: ffmpeg, cpu-usage, x264

I want to convert a mkv formatted video to mp4, using the *ffmpeg* application.
and for that I ran below command in terminal:

`ffmpeg -y -i c38a4990774b3c23.mkv -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -r 25 -strict -2 -map_metadata -1 -movflags faststart -vf "crop=1920:800:0:4, scale=iw*min(426/iw\,240/ih):ih*min(426/iw\,240/ih), pad=426:240:(426-iw*min(426/iw\,240/ih))/2:(240-ih*min(426/iw\,240/ih))/2, setsar=sar=1" output.mp4`

> I have compiled ffmpeg with --enable-pthread configuration

when I run this command on my personal PC with a 3.2GHz quad core cpu, it uses 60% of overall cpu process and encode video with 150fps; **but** when I run this command on a production server with 8 2.4GHz dual core cpu (16 core) it only uses up to **20%** of overall cpu process and encode video with 97fps.

I have also tried *ramdisk* but I got no performance improvement.

Comment: You'll need to know the CPU microarchitecture of your PC and that of the production server to, at best, gain some high level insights.  Also it's possible that one box is using hyperthreading (thus showing a 2x core count) whereas the other box is not, further muddying the waters.  Perhaps your prod server has multi-socket Xeons, so most likely an older microarchitecture.  If it has hyperthreading, then effectively only 8 cores can use SIMD.

Comment: Adding a little to the microarchitecture comment: The most recent architectures have 512-bit SIMD whereas earlier have 256-bit (and even smaller for much earlier architectures). Are you using the same binary? See if you can find out which compiler was used in constructing the application on the server. Compilers (and versions) differ in their effectiveness in making use of newer architectural features. I believe that GNU now has AVX-512 support but that support may not be the default.